# "Undefined variable: products (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\producto\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)"

Tags: php, laravel, undefined

He creado un controlador para la vista Welcome estática que viene por defecto en laravel, quiero que me muestre datos de forma dinámica pero no logro hacerlo. esto es lo que tengo.

**web.php:**

```
Route::get('/', function(){
return view('welcome' );
});
Route::get('welcome', 'WelcomeController@index')->name('welcome');
Route::resource('welcome','WelcomeController');
```

**WelcomeController.php:**

```
public function index(){
$products=Product::query('id', 'DESC')->get();
return view('welcome', compact('products'));
}
```

**El error que me da:**

```
"Undefined variable: products (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\producto\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)"
```

Comment: Puedes poner lo que tienes en tu archivo `welcome.blade.php`

Comment: cual es la url que te da el problema?

Comment: @EdwinAquino funciona bien el template, si utilizo redirect fuciona bien la vista usando el siguiente script 
Route::redirect('/','welcome');

Route::get('welcome', 'WelcomeController@index')->name('welcome');
Route::resource('welcome','WelcomeController'); pero no quiero que sea por redirect por que la url quedaria www.ejemplo.com/welcome y eso es lo que no quiero

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema lo tienes aquí Jorge:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
return view('welcome' );
});
```

Piensa esto: en tu vista llamas a la variable $products, pero en la ruta que has definido (la que te pongo arriba), **no estas pasando por el controller** que es lugar donde declaras $products, con lo que directamente se carga la vista "welcome" y la variable $products, que no has declarado, se llama en la vista y por eso "explota".

Para que lo veas un poco mejor, en la segunda que pones:

```
Route::get('welcome', 'WelcomeController@index')->name('welcome');
```

Ahí sí que estará declarada $products cuando se cargue la vista, ya que lo que haces es llamar al controlador WelcomeController (el cual declara la variable en cuestion) y luego ya llamas a la vista pasandole la variable.

Soluciones:

- En tu primera ruta puedes declarar products antes de devolver la vista (y pasarsela) pero no lo acabo de ver del todo correcto. En el routes no debería haber variables por ahí así como así.
- Creo que lo mejor sería que llames a un controller (bien sea el propio WelcomeController u otro que te crees), y hagas más o menos lo mismo que haces en la segunda ruta (declarar la variable, llamar a la vista y pasar dicha variable).

Comment: Esto habia intentado tambien, carga el layuouts.app pero no el contenido que tengo en welcome.blade.php     Route::get('/', function(){
    $products=Route::resource('welcome','WelcomeController');
    return view('welcome',compact('products'));
});

Comment: lo soluciones de esta manera:  Route::get('/', function(){
    $products=Product::query('id', 'DESC')->get();
    return view('welcome', compact('products'));
});  aunque no creo que sea una buena practica por que estoy evitando WelcomeController.php

Comment: @JorgeGomez lo que comentas es lo que te pongo en la opción  1, pero bajo mi punto de vista no es lo correcto. El archivo routes.php no está creado con ese proposito, sino con el de mapear las rutas a tu aplicación (como su nombre indica). Te aconsejo que sigas (por ejemplo) el punto 2 o utilices otra solución.